# SBT : Auto versioning of artifacts

Tags: scala, sbt, versioning

We have a Scala project which we are building via CI tool (TeamCity/Jenkins). We are looking for an ability to set the build version of the artifact from the build job itself and not depend on the entry in `build.sbt` file. To give a reference, for java maven builds we can use goal set-version where the artifact version is set, irrespective of what we have in pom.xml. we are looking for something similar for a SBT build as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change version in build.sbt custom task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48701025/change-version-in-build-sbt-custom-task)

Answer (score 2):

I'd reccoment to take a look at next sbt plugins:

- https://github.com/dwijnand/sbt-dynver
- https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git

Our team uses `sbt-dynver` to create version from Git, because it is easier. I'd recommend to build version on top of git tags information rather then using CI tool (TeamCity/Jenkins) information - like build number, because you can build same version twice for instance.

Also, consider using https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo - additionally, so to expose build version though API or print to output to quick identify currently deployed app version.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really the right forum for this kind of recommendation, but you could start by looking a [sbt-git](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git) which will set version numbers based on GIT tags.

Answer (score 0):

One option your have, is to add this to your `build.sbt`:

```
version := sys.env.getOrElse("ARTIFACT_VERSION", "0.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
```

Then setting the version you want at the environment variable `ARTIFACT_VERSION`.